# Ghostscript spatie/pdf-to-image

Tags: laravel, ghostscript

I am using spatie/pdf-to-image to convert pdf to jpg on a laravel web app. To do that I need first to install Imagick and Ghostscript. I did install the Imagick but I don't know how to install ghostscript. I am hosting my app on Godaddy shared hosting. any help?

Comment: I will be glad to help you. Move off of Godaddy Shared hosting and look into using `laravel forge` with a cheap Digital Ocean VPS. You'll never be happier. GoDaddy shared hosting is not meant for full stack control.

Comment: This is the error I get in Laravel:    ImagickException in vendor/spatie/pdf-to-image/src/Pdf.php line 169:
PDFDelegateFailed `[ghostscript library] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r144x144" -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 "-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-15967W9yJYObtH6D7%d" "-f/tmp/magick-15967RuRHmr8uSUvO" "-f/tmp/magick-15967K2EbNM1u5Onv"': -dname= must be followed by a valid token
@ error/pdf.c/InvokePDFDelegate/263

Comment: @user3708740 did you ever solve your issue?